# Size of kernel built is much much larger than the built-in one

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I got latest kernel source from kernel.org(using git), and followed the steps as described in [this page](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) to build the kernel. The kernel boots successfully, however, I have no idea what was done incorrectly in the configuration process that initrd.img-3.16.0 is so much larger than the build in one(initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic)

I copied the configuration file .config from /boot/ and used "yes '' | make oldconfig" for the kernel configuration.

the file size `total 191M
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jul 14 21:29 abi-3.13.0-32-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 162K Jul 14 21:29 config-3.13.0-32-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 167K Aug  4 19:48 config-3.16.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20M Jul 28 15:14 initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151M Aug  4 19:48 initrd.img-3.16.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173K Mar 12 05:31 memtest86+.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 174K Mar 12 05:31 memtest86+.elf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175K Mar 12 05:31 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
    -rw------- 1 root root 3.3M Jul 14 21:29 System.map-3.13.0-32-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4M Aug  4 19:48 System.map-3.16.0
    -rw------- 1 root root 5.6M Jul 14 21:29 vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.7M Aug  4 19:48 vmlinuz-3.16.0`

Thanks!
William

Comment: I am using `make-kpkg --initrd binary`  on Debian to build a kernel.

Comment: What do you see when you diff the old and the new config?

Comment: Hi, n.m., I can see the new configurations available(from 3.16 vs. 3.13) has all the new configurations configured as 'y'. That's basically all the options we can see doing "make listnewconfig". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks, Basile, but it's still the same. I still think somehow I have a mistake generating the .config process

Comment: are you using yes "" | make oldconfig which will use default values for all options.

Comment: Hi, Arsane, yes, I did that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps to obtain the right kernel configuration

> 1. Copy /boot/.config to the kernel source code directory
> 2. make menuconfig
> 3. Exit and save configuration
> 4. make

and then continue with the other options for install

Note : Since you are using **make oldconfig**, this would enable many of the options not related to the platform but related to the CPU architecture.

This steps should help you solve this issue

Comment: Thanks, Santosh! I tried this step too but unfortunately ended up with the same result. Looks like "make menuconfig" would set new configurations to y by default(when I did a diff between the default config and the one saved after menuconfig.

Comment: What was the size of the kernel after following this procedure

Comment: Hi, Santosh, it's 156MB. I'm now trying https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

Comment: Hi RAX, can you share the .config from /boot

Comment: I'm really sorry guys, my bad in the question description. I've just updated the problem description. It's initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic which is significantly larger(151MB vs. 20MB)